# Can I use an idiom "laid out" in such meaning?

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-usage

I want to say that her future is assured and wealthy.

Can I do so by saying:

**"Her future was laid out before her"**, preferably without *before her*.

Can the meaning apply at least figuratively or does that just sound weird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when we say someone's future was laid out before him/her, it suggests that perhaps a higher power, tradition, or destiny has already written one's future. It is often used to describe what are perceived to be certain key events in one's life to which one can trace his or her success, but it can also convey a total lack of control over a life one doesn't necessarily want.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that, but it sounds a bit awkward and doesn't suggest future wealth. Try "A prosperous future lay before her."